# using GM to click button with no name or id

Tags: javascript, button, greasemonkey

Original PHP Code :

```
var button='';

button+='<table border="0"id="table1"cellspacing="0"cellpadding="2"><tr><td>';
button+='<button type="submit" name="B5"style="height: 20; background-color: #0000FF; width:20" onclick="submitform(2);"></button></td>';
button+='<td>';button+='<button type="submit" name="B5"style="height: 20; background-color: #FFFF00; width:20" onclick="wrong();"></button></td>';
button+='</tr><tr><td>';button+='<button type="submit" name="B5"style="height: 20; background-color: #008000; width:20" onclick="wrong();"></button></td>';
button+='<td>';button+='<button type="submit" name="B5"style="height: 20; background-color: #FFFFFF; width:20" onclick="wrong();"></button></td>';

var button2='<button type="submit"  name="B6" style="height: 20; background-color: #0000FF; width:20" disabled></button>';
```

In this situation I want to click the button that has the `onclick` value of `submitform(2);` but with no value or id and the same name.

I'm lost, here's what I've tried ...

```
function clickb5 (jNode) {
var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
//-- Value match is case-sensitive
waitForKeyElements (
//"#btn_submit input[type='submit'][onclick*=submitform(1);]",
"input[type='submit'][onclick*=submitform(1);]",
clickb5
);
```

`onclick*=submitform(1);` also comes with () value 0,1,2,3 depending on page.

But one thing at a time ...

Could someone help? Thanks!

Solution that works but not the *best* - help with getting random time?

```
setTimeout(Greasemonkey_main, 10000);

function Greasemonkey_main () {
unsafeWindow.submitform(0);
unsafeWindow.submitform(1);
unsafeWindow.submitform(2);
unsafeWindow.submitform(3);
}
```

Thanks All!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with that selector:

1. `input[type='submit'][onclick*=submitform(1);]` searches for an `<input>`, but the control you want is a `<button>`.
2. `[onclick*=submitform(1);]` is a syntax error in jQuery.  Always put such values in quotes.  In this case it would be: `[onclick*='submitform(1)']`.
3. Trailing space and semicolons tend to disappear with page changes.  So omit those from selectors for more durable code.

---

The actual control, that you appear to be trying to click, has HTML like this:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="submitform(1);" ...></button>
```

For that, your code should be:

```
waitForKeyElements (
    "button[onclick*='submitform(1)']"",
    clickb5
);

function clickb5 (jNode) {
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

---

---

---

I do not recommend it (it might have timing problems and it uses `unsafeWindow` unnecessarily), but for completeness, it *might* be possible that you could replace all that code with:

```
unsafeWindow.submitform(1);
```

Again, this is not recommended and it is not a robust solution if the site is AJAX driven.

Comment: hmm i'm not sure - seems to be a problem with finding the key element .. I tried this to see if it was even showing up, because it wasnt clicking ...                                                                     waitForKeyElements (
    "button[onclick*='submitform(1)']"",
    clickb5
    );

    function clickb5 {
    alert("Hello, world!");
    }

Comment: is it because the php is generating the html like 3 secs after load? however that's the whole reason I did the waitforkey element thing... This work but fires off immeditly - i'd rather it be rnd between 5-7 secs :: window.addEventListener ("load", Greasemonkey_main, false);
setTimeout(Greasemonkey_main, 10000);

function Greasemonkey_main () {
 unsafeWindow.submitform(0);
 unsafeWindow.submitform(1);
 unsafeWindow.submitform(2);
 unsafeWindow.submitform(3);
}

Comment: Edit your question to add code.  Don't try to put more than about 40 characters of code in comments!  And yes, `waitForKeyElements`  is designed to work around such delays. If it's firing too soon, you're not waiting for the right thing.

Comment: I tried editing question and it wouldnt let me? I know my last message was a bit of a mess but it was using your non-recommended way not using waitForKeyElements. I have it submit on load then try to delay it - probably a problem with that lol

Comment: yep it was --- 'code' setTimeout(Greasemonkey_main, 10000);  How can I get that to be random between 5-10 secs?

Comment: You can edit your own question! (Heck, ***anyone*** can edit your question, via the suggested-edit mechanism.) As for that last comment, that would be a different question than this one (which is now answered, apparently?).

Comment: i can do a static time  but dont know how to do a random time without messing up my code, lol.

Comment: The random time thing is something you would address in a new question.  But search around first, that kind of thing's been asked a few times.  Mark this Q answered if you want my help with the next one. (There are thousands of other guys who might help anyway.)

Comment: marked as answered - though i'm still puzzeled why the waitforkey element part did not work.

Comment: Can't say without seeing the actual page; but it looks like you are wanting to click or submit 4 buttons/forms. The original code, that you posted, would do only one. `waitForKeyElements` works fine on my test page, which I made using the snippet of HTML you provided.

Comment: each time the page loads it's 1 of those 4 possibilities that's why i was trying to get the code basis for just one then work off it from there. I'll repost more of the php that creates the html if you wanna look at it in your free time. Thanks again for your help :)